# RegularExpressions not working

Tags: regex, vb.net

Here is my code:

```
    Dim StartString As String = "Private Sub"
    Dim EndString As String = "End Sub"

    Dim SearchString As String = StartString & "(.+)" & EndString

    Dim Data() As String = New Regex(SearchString).Matches(Text).Cast(Of Match).Select(Function(m) m.Groups(1).Value).ToArray
```

This is the value of Text:

```
Public Class Form1

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim x As Integer

    x = 10
    MessageBox.Show(x / "Simon")

End Sub

Private Function Test()

    Dim x As Integer

    x = 30
    MessageBox.Show(x / "Test")

End Function
```

End Class

How come my Data array is not populated with any data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect it's because you are attempting to make your pattern match over multiple lines.

The `.` character matches anything **except** newline `\n`, and the body of the `Private Sub/End Sub` you want to match has newlines in it.

You have to enable the regex option `SingleLine` (see [the msdn for regular expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972966.aspx)):

> `SingleLine`
>   Has nothing to do with how many lines are in the input
>   string. Rather, will cause the . (period) metacharacter to match **any**
>   character, **instead of any character except \n**, which is the default.

So, try `New Regex(SearchString,RegexOptions.SingleLine)` instead of `New Regex(SearchString)`.